# From for loop to Java 8 Stream example

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I would like a simple example for Java 8 `Streams` to understand it. I have this code that returns a free taxi. I would like to replace this for loop with equivalent code that uses Java 8 streams :

```
private List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<Taxi>();

Taxi scheduleTaxi(){
    for (Taxi taxi : taxis) {
        if (taxi.isFree()) {
            return taxi;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I iterate over a list of `taxis`, and evaluate if `taxi` respects the condition. If the condition applies, I stop the loop and return `taxi`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `return taxis.stream().filter(Taxi::isFree).findFirst().orElse(null);`. The last one is not a `Stream` method, but an `Optional` method.

Comment: If you're going to use a `Stream`, Andreas is correct, but you should probably leave off the `orElse(null)` and instead return an [`Optional<Taxi>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) since it will give you some handy methods like [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: @4castle I decided to write a [long answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39540979/5221149), and I incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is this:

```
return taxis.stream()
            .filter(Taxi::isFree)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```

Here is a list of the expression steps with their return type and *links to javadoc*:

**Expression Step**         | **Type**                    | **Alternative**
`taxis`                           | [`List<Taxi>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
[`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--)                      | [`Stream<Taxi>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)     | [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--)
[`filter(Taxi::isFree)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) | `Stream<Taxi>`
[`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--)                 | [`Optional<Taxi>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) | [`findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--)
[`orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)               | `Taxi`                   | *none, see below*

---

The `filter(Taxi::isFree)` call is using a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
It can also be written using a [*lambda expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
filter(t -> t.isFree())
```

or using a *lambda expression block*:

```
filter(t -> {
    return t.isFree();
})
```

The parameter can also specify a type, to be more explicit:

```
filter((Taxi t) -> { return t.isFree(); })
```

which makes it look more like the [*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) it's equivalent to:

```
filter(new Predicate<Taxi>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Taxi t) {
        return t.isFree();
    }
})
```

---

As @4castle [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540691/from-for-loop-to-streams-example#comment66395439_39540691), depending on the needs of your `scheduleTaxi()` method, you might want to change the return type and skip the last step, to make it explicit to the caller that it might not be able to find a taxi.

```
Optional<Taxi> scheduleTaxi() {
    return taxis.stream().filter(Taxi::isFree).findFirst();
}
```

Comment: I know this is the same as OPs code but the text just mentions finding a free taxi. If some randomness is ok and the list of taxis is decently large, a parallel stream and the use of the `findAny` method versus the `findFirst` method may have some value.

Comment: @AaronDavis Which is why I listed `parallelStream()` and `findAny()` as *alternatives*, but the primary calls shown is the direct equivalent to the original code. I'm leaving it up to readers of this answer to read the javadoc of the various methods and learn about the differences for themselves. They can always create questions here on StackOverflow is they then have *specific* questions about those differences.

Comment: Ha..I missed that that was in the later part of your answer. That'll teach me to comment on answers while on my phone without fully reading them :-)

Answer (score 9):

Using the newest [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.3+EAP) (either Community edition or Ultimate edition), you can convert it automatically. Just put the cursor on your for-loop:

[image: Idea]

Press the Alt-Enter and select "Replace with findFirst()":

[image: Idea]

Voila, it's done!

[image: Idea]

**Disclaimer**: I'm IntelliJ IDEA developer.

Answer (score 0):

Comments kinda said it already, but I'll explain *a bit* more:

```
private List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<Taxi>();
Optional<Taxi> optTaxi = taxis.stream().filter(taxi -> taxi.isFree()).findFirst() //or findAny()
```

Here is what happens logically: after getting a stream from your list, you use `filter` which basically takes conditions, checks which of the items in your list meet them, and returns a stream with only these items. Then `findFirst/Any` grabs the first/any item and returns it as an `Optional`. If no items "survive" the filtering, that `Optional` will contain `null`.

Just mind you that the order of code execution is not the same as I described because streams work differently. If you do `filter(...).filter(...).filter(...)` it won't iterate over and over, just one time.

Back to your code: you can return the `Optional<Taxi>` itself or unpack it and return the `Taxi` object, which can be `null` depending on what you want.